# Bing's house, but with n rooms?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Chapter 0 of his *Algebraic Topology*, Hatcher presents Bing's house with two rooms as an example of a space that is contractible, but "not in any obvious way."  He then asks, as an exercise (Chapter 0, exercise 8), for the reader to construct a  similar house, but with $n$ rooms.  Here's my problem.  I can easily make a house with two rooms that *is* contractible in an obvious way.  Start with a brick of clay; poke a hole in the top and hollow out a room in the *top* half of the brick; then do the same starting from the bottom.  Clearly I can make an $n$-room house in the same way, poking holes in $n$ spots on the brick, but this is also clearly not what Hatcher is looking for.  Somehow, Bing's house--which you get by poking a hole in the top and hollowing out a room in the *bottom*, and vice versa--is more interesting than mine, even though they're topologically equivalent.  I need to understand precisely what the difference is in order to construct an $n$-room analog with the same qualities.  What is it?